# Batch file to check Windows services and Start them

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I am trying to create a batch file that will sort 7 windows services into a list then check one by one if they're running, and if they aren't, start them.

What I have doesn't seem to be wokring and seems to echo set i=o. I am trying to find out how to properly execute the two for loops and if anybody has any suggestions for syntax that would be awesome

I was able to create a very primitive version but wanted to learn more about batch file "programming". This is what I've come up with so far:

```
    ::Enter in CC number
    set /p CC=Enter The Site's CC:

    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    ::Create vector with names of services
    set i=0
    for %%s in 
    ("Apache Tomcat"
        "OracleServicePD"
        "OracleXETNSListener_bqw"
        "System Audit Service"
        "RPOS ScemComms Service"
        "RPOS debit credit service"
        "RPOS Remote Device Service"
        "RPOS Messaging Service"
        ) do (
        set /A i=i+1
        set services[!i!]=%%s
        )

    ::Check if all services are running, if not go to it's respective net start method
    ::After all is checked, it goes to :check to show services are running  
    set n=0
    :loop
    for /L %%G in (0,1,7) do (
        net start | find !services[%n%]! > nul 2>&1 
        if not "%errorlevel%"=="0"
        set pathname=!services[%n%]!
        set /A n=n+1
        goto %pathname%
        )

    goto check

    :"Apache Tomcat" 
    net start tomcat6
    goto loop

    :"OracleServicePD"
    net start "OracleServicePD%CC%"
    goto loop

    :"OracleXETNSListener_bqw"
    net start "OracleXETNSListener_bqw"
    goto loop

    :"System Audit Service"
    net start "System Audit Service"
    goto loop

    :"RPOS ScemComms Service"
    net start "RPOS ScemComms Service"
    goto loop

    :"RPOS debit credit service"
    net start "RPOS debit credit service"
    goto loop

    :"RPOS Remote Device Service"
    net start "RPOS Remote Device Service"
    goto loop

    :"RPOS Messaging Service"
    net start "RPOS Messaging Service"
    goto loop

    :check

    echo Apache Tomcat && sc query tomcat6 | find "STATE"
    echo OracleServicePD%CC% && sc query "OracleServicePD%CC%" | find "STATE"
    echo OracleXETNSListener_bqw && sc query "OracleXETNSListener_bqw" | find "STATE"
    echo System Audit Service && sc query "System Audit Service" | find "STATE"
    echo RPOS ScemComms Service && sc query "RPOS ScemComms Service" | find "STATE"
    echo RPOS debit credit service && sc query "RPOS debit credit service" | find "STATE"
    echo RPOS Remote Device Service && sc query "RPOS Remote Device Service" | find "STATE"
    echo RPOS Messaging Service && sc query "RPOS Messaging Service" | find "STATE"
```

Comment: You forgot to add the question!

Answer (score 0):

first, your first service is services[1], but your loop starts with 0.

more importantly, where does %n% come from? you mean %%G here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc start AeLookupSvc&&echo Started||(sc start AeLookupSvc|Findstr /c:"1056"&&Echo Already Running||Echo Error starting service)
```

Your pattern of testing then doing is not a good programming technique. You do and test if it worked.

The above does one service and reports if already running, if it was started, or what error prevents it starting. All in one line.

**From MSDos 6.22 Help File**.

```
│The following list shows each exit code and a brief description of its
│meaning:
│
│0
│    The search was completed successfully and at least one match was found.
│
│1
│    The search was completed successfully, but no matches were found.
│
│2
│    The search was not completed successfully. In this case, an error
│    occurred during the search, and FIND cannot report whether any matches
│    were found.
│
│You can use the ERRORLEVEL parameter on the  command line in a batch
│program to process exit codes returned by FIND.
```

A list of command line things.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```

### .